# Help Alice and Bob divide up their finances

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Our friends Alice and Bob must separate their finances. They divide up the first 18 items as follows.

| Alice | Bob |
| --- | --- |
| Apartment | House |
| Fee | Owe |
| Purchase | Sell |
| Money | Income |
| Lease | Borrow |
| Debt | Loan |
| Tax | Buy |
| Collateral | Lend |
| Renter | Boarder |

They're left with these 8 items to divide.

- Bond
- Deed
- Interest
- Land
- Lien
- Loss
- Mortgage
- Title

Can you follow the pattern to help Alice and Bob finish splitting the 26 items? The items will divide evenly.

| Alice | Bob |
| --- | --- |
| Apartment | House |
| Fee | Owe |
| Purchase | Sell |
| Money | Income |
| Lease | Borrow |
| Debt | Loan |
| Tax | Buy |
| Collateral | Lend |
| Renter | Boarder |
| ? | ? |
| ? | ? |
| ? | ? |
| ? | ? |

Hint #1

> The task is merely to separate the items, so order does not matter. 13 of the 26 items go to Alice, the other 13 items go to Bob.

Hint #2

> The pattern does not depend on word length, vowel counting, or letter counting of any kind. No computer or calculator is required.

Comment: Alice and Bob really ought to hire a professional divorce arbitrator instead of asking random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Alice gets the item whose etymology is Old French (just like her name).

| Alice | Bob |
| --- | --- |
| Lien | Bond |
| Mortgage | Deed |
| Title | Land |
| Interest | Loss |